# How to check if a string is valid XPATH or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

in my project I have to vailidate if a given string is valid XPath or not.I have searched but there is no example to validate it.Is it possible using java-script?
For example if I use the string //elements/element that will be valid and invalid XPATH is like this //elements@element[

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: can you please post your code.?

Comment: I am not gettingany starting point thats why I have posted.

Comment: Use chrome dev tool.Go to console and type `$x("xpath")[0]` if your xpath valid it will return node else throw error.  link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: It's not clear from your question neither your comments to @Phil [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213595/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-valid-xpath-or-not-in-javascript#comment100933724_57213718) what is the meaning of valid XPath: an expression that effectively selects something or an expression withput syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You could always wrap [`Document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) in `try..catch`, eg

```js
try {
  document.evaluate(xpathExpression, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Provided XPath expression is not valid', e)
}
```

When the expression is not valid, the evaluation fails with something like...

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '<your xpath expression>' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I can't use document.evaluate because I have only the XPATH string not the document.I only need to check if the string matches a valid XPATH pattern.

Comment: Your question really doesn't make much sense. You could improve that by adding some expectations, eg what results in a pass and what results in a fail